# HTML in string interpolation with string

Tags: javascript, angular

How to write HTML with string in string interpolation ,

I want on load it should show Processing .... "loader"

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="onAjaxCall" (click)="onSave()">
  {{ onAjaxCall ? 'Processing ...'+
            <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-3x fa-fw"></i> : 'Save' }}
</button>
```

It doesn't work correctly , the I tag show always

Comment: What does "doesn't work correctly" mean? Please read [ask]

Comment: systax you are tring is not allowed in interpolation ..you can have look to my answer and visit link

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="onAjaxCall" (click)="onSave()">
       <span *ngIf="onAjaxCall">Processing...<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-3x fa-fw"></i></span>
       <span *ngIf="!onAjaxCall">Save:</span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

just for the information form angular.io website (Read here : https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax)

JavaScript expressions that have or promote side effects are prohibited, including:

```
- assignments (=, +=, -=, ...)
- new
- chaining expressions with ; or ,
- increment and decrement operators (++ and --)
```

So for your case i do suggest make use of method and call it form you template syntax.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="onAjaxCall" (click)="onSave()">
  {{ methodcall() }}
</button>
```

in compoent write method this will return output of

```
method():string
{
  return 
 this.onAjaxCall ? 'Processing ...'+<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-3x fa-fw"></i> : 'Save';
}
```